# How to combine a top-down and bottom-up binary tree in one picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, trees

I want to draw a binary tree like the one in the picture below. Unfortunately, I do not have any clue, whatsoever, on how to draw two trees from top and bottom to match their leaves. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you have some code to share about your attempts?

Comment: @ergreg Thank you! But I only have the code for top tree using tikzpicture, which i think won't help anyone here. In the meantime, I will try to study the code provided by Mr. Medina. Thank you again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}

\newsavebox\Downtree
\newsavebox\Uptree

\tikzset{
  nleft/.style={text width=15pt,midway,left,font=\strut\scriptsize},
  nright/.style={text width=15pt,midway,right,font=\strut\scriptsize},
  }

\savebox\Downtree{\begin{forest}
for tree={
  s sep=25pt,
  l sep=20pt,
  where n children=0{inner ysep=0pt}{draw,circle},
  edge={->,>=latex}
}
[Y3
  [Y2,edge label={node[nleft]{yes}}
    [,edge label={node[nleft]{yes}}]
    [,edge label={node[nright]{no}}]
  ]
  [Y1,edge label={node[nright]{no}}
    [,edge label={node[nleft]{yes}}]
    [,edge label={node[nright]{no}}]
  ]
]
\end{forest}%
}
\savebox\Uptree{\begin{forest}
for tree={
  grow'=north,
  s sep=25pt,
  l sep=20pt,
  where n children=0{inner ysep=0pt}{draw,circle},
  edge={->,>=latex}
}
[X3
  [X4,edge label={node[nleft]{no}}
    [,edge label={node[nleft]{no}}]
    [,edge label={node[nright]{yes}}]
  ]
  [X1,edge label={node[nright]{yes}}
    [,edge label={node[nleft]{no}}]
    [,edge label={node[nright]{yes}}]
  ]
]
\end{forest}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Latex[open]}]
\node[inner sep=0pt] (Down) {\usebox\Downtree};
\coordinate (aux);
\node[inner sep=0pt,below=0pt of Down] (Up) {\usebox\Uptree};
\begin{scope}[red,->]
\draw
  ([xshift=-15pt,yshift=-10pt]Down.north) to[bend right] (Down.south west);
\draw
  ([xshift=-15pt,yshift=10pt]Up.south) to[bend left] (Up.north west);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[blue,->]
\draw
  ([xshift=15pt,yshift=-10pt]Down.north) to[bend left] (Down.south east);
\draw
  ([xshift=15pt,yshift=10pt]Up.south) to[bend right] (Up.north east);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[green,<->]
\draw
  ([xshift=-2pt]Down.south) 
  .. controls ++(-10pt,2cm) and ++(10pt,2cm) .. 
  ([xshift=2pt]Down.south);
\draw
  ([xshift=-2pt]Up.north) 
  .. controls ++(-10pt,-2cm) and ++(10pt,-2cm) .. 
  ([xshift=2pt]Up.north);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I used the [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package to build two separate trees; one of then growing downwards, and the other one, growing upwards. Each tree is first boxed and then the boxes are placed inside `\node`s in a `tikzpicture` to easily draw the red and green arrows.

Comment: Thank you @Gonzalo. It works like a charm and the code is also clear to understand. I see that there is a big space between the two trees. If I just change the "below" property of downtree node to negative values, I can squeeze the space, but suddenly all the arrows start to mess up. I appreciate++ your extra help in advanced. :)

Comment: @kailashbuki You're welcome! I changed the code; specifically, I changed `where n children=0{}{draw,circle}` to `where n children=0{inner ysep=0pt}{draw,circle}` so now leaves won't take that much vertical space; in this way, the separation between the two trees decreases and now the `below` key allows better controlling of the vertical spacing; I also simplified the code for the edge labels using some styles. Let me know if this produces the desired result.

Answer (score 4):

Although you want to draw trees, there's no need to use `Tikz trees`, `tikz-qtree`, `forest`, ... for drawing them. A `matrix` like in next code or just correctly positioned nodes can do the same.

And next code doesn't insert a `tikzpicture` inside another `tikzpicture` which sometimes is not recommended.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, nodes={circle,draw},
             row 3/.style={nodes={draw=none, inner sep=0pt},nodes in empty cells},
             row sep=.75cm, column sep=3mm]
{
&[4mm]&&&Y3&&&&[4mm]\\
&&Y2&&&&Y1&&\\
&&&&&&&&\\
&&X4&&&&X1&&\\
&&&&X3&&&&\\
};
\draw[->] (A-1-5)--  node[above left]{yes} (A-2-3);
\draw[->] (A-1-5)-- node[above right]{no} (A-2-7) ;
\draw[->] (A-2-3)--  node[above left]{yes} (A-3-2);
\draw[->] (A-2-3)-- node[above right]{no} (A-3-4) ;
\draw[->] (A-2-7)--  node[above left]{yes} (A-3-6);
\draw[->] (A-2-7)-- node[above right]{no} (A-3-8) ;

\draw[->] (A-5-5)--  node[below left]{no} (A-4-3);
\draw[->] (A-5-5)-- node[below right]{yes} (A-4-7) ;
\draw[->] (A-4-3)--  node[below left]{no} (A-3-2);
\draw[->] (A-4-3)-- node[below right]{yes} (A-3-4) ;
\draw[->] (A-4-7)--  node[below left]{no} (A-3-6);
\draw[->] (A-4-7)-- node[below right]{yes} (A-3-8) ;

\draw[red,->, >={Latex[open]},shorten <=3mm] (A-1-5.north) to[out=180,in=90] (A-3-1);
\draw[red,->, >={Latex[open]},shorten <=3mm] (A-5-5.south) to[out=180,in=-90] (A-3-1);
\draw[blue,->, >={Latex[open]},shorten <=3mm] (A-1-5.north) to[out=0,in=90] (A-3-9);
\draw[blue,->, >={Latex[open]},shorten <=3mm] (A-5-5.south) to[out=0,in=-90] (A-3-9);

\draw[green,<->, >={Latex[open]},shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (A-3-5) to[loop above,min distance=2cm] (A-3-5);
\draw[green,<->, >={Latex[open]},shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (A-3-5) to[loop below,min distance=2cm] (A-3-5);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]